# iOS scaling with CGAffineTransformMakeScale on drawRect content

Tags: ios, core-graphics, scale, cgaffinetransform

```
    float scaleFactor = 0.5;
    self.bubble.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    [self.bubble setNeedsDisplay];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        self.frame = _rectToMoveTo;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
            self.bubble.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        }];
    }];
```

The above code performs the animation mostly correct. As you can see, the `self.bubble`s are scaled down to ½ then animated back to normal. The problem is that self.bubble has a `drawRect` method for drawing a circle. The problem is that this circle gets scaled down to ¼ from the start! When the second animation runs, the subviews of `self.bubble` get scaled to normal, but the circle scales up to only ½. I've tried using `setNeedsDisplay` to redraw the circle but it will only work after the animations have completed so it's no good. how do you fix this?

Edit: here is _bubble drawRect method.

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (!_colour) _colour = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [_colour setFill];
    [[UIColor clearColor] setStroke];

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height));

    CGContextFillPath(c);

    [self addSubview:_title];
    [self addSubview:_icon];
```

Comment: Perhaps show the (relevant part of) the `drawRect` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.frame` is in the superview's coordinate system, and is thus affected by your transform, which you don't want.

Inside `drawRect:`, you should only use `self.bounds`, not `self.frame`.

Also, you should not add subviews in `drawRect:`.

Comment: Thank you! I moved my `addSubview:`s to the initWith... method and changed frame to bounds in the `drawRect:` and it worked!

Comment: @robmayoff Hope you don't mind, but: why should we use `self.bounds` and not `self.frame` and not adding subviews in `drawRect`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig `self.frame` is in the superview's coordinate system.  `self.bounds` is in your own coordinate system.  The drawing functions operate in your own coordinate system, not your superview's coordinate system.  If you try to use coordinates or sizes from your superview's coordinate system when drawing in your own coordinate system, you may get incorrect results.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks +1, Rob. Just one more thing (sorry), why shouldn't we add subviews in `drawRect`?